# PostgreSQL and South migrations sequences

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-south

I switched from MySQL to PostgreSQL and running migrations and it is a bit strange after MySQL. When I run `./manage.py migrate` on a clean db, whenever the migration comes to a field which is ForeignKey or any other relation field, which is not yet created in db, it raises an error and stops. In MySQL you just run migrate and it does all for you, MySQL created these non-existing fields.

So can I somehow to control the execution of migrations like, please postgres go and do that migration first and that second and so on, because otherwise all you gotta do is do migrate manually one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set dependencies between migrations, as described in the [docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependencies.html).